# get transliterated text Except translated text

Tags: python, text, googletrans

Whenever I Used googletrans API to convert my English text to any Indian language like Gujrati,
what happens is that, it gives me translated text except converted text.

I'll give you an example  like,

```
Name = 'Happy'

result = translator.translate(Name, src='en',dest='gu')

Expected O/p : હે પી

o/p: ખુશ
```

here result is translated text, not transliterated text

Comment: Given that none of the English speaking users of this site understand the difference between "હે પી" and "ખુશ", it is not clear at all what you are asking. As far as I can see, you asked for a translation and you got a translation.

Comment: @zvone "ખુશ" is the meaning of "happy" and "હે પી" == "happy"
please refer this link : https://www.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RE56vhu
(page no: 5-6)

Comment: So you are saying it is a transliteration? Well, AFAIK Google Translate does not have a transliteration option, so it must be the best translation it was able to do, either because it does not know how to translate or because Gujrati speakers actually sometimes say "happy".

Comment: This is **not** a Python issue *per se*. It's how googletrans works. Maybe it's a limitation but that's a matter for the googletrans developer whose details are available [here](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/)

Comment: @zvone I think  you'll understand what I meant in this question, so can you please edit my question for a better understanding of viewers

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you are not supplying enough context for the translation engine. It might not have enough samples of text pairs where "happy" was correctly translated, or there are competing text pairs where "happy" was left untranslated (perhaps it's a popular brand or service in your area?) Try supplying more words, like "she is very happy" or "happy birthday"